# Why there is output difference for give code in c++ 11 and c++ 17?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++17, postfix-operator

I have a piece  of code

```
     #include <bits/stdc++.h>
      using namespace std;
      typedef long long ll ; 
      int main() 
      { 
             ios_base::sync_with_stdio(0);cin.tie(0);cout.tie(0) ; 
             int i, j;
             i = j = 5;
             j = i++ + (i*10);
             cout<<i<<" "<< j <<" "<<i++;

    }
```

Output of code for c++ 17 is : 6 65 6
Output of code for c++ 11 is : 7 65 6

Why such a difference ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why are these constructs using pre and post-increment undefined behavior?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/949433/why-are-these-constructs-using-pre-and-post-increment-undefined-behavior)

Comment: What compiler(s) are you using, and with what flags?

Answer (score 1):

Before C++17, the expression `j = i++ + (i*10);` exhibited undefined behavior.

In C++17, the language rules were changed to define the behavior of such expressions. (ones that modify a variable and use it in the same expression)

So, depending on your compiler, your platform, the optimization settings that you are using, the phase of the moon, etc, you *might* get the same answer ... or not.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the C++17 changes? Off the top of my head, this still looks undefined.

Comment: ` i++ + (i*10)` afaik the access to `i` is still unsequenced.